# Select * from Items where Convert(date, DueDate) = @today

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am having trouble with a simple select.  The database field that stored DueDate is a DateTimeOffset.

```
 declare @today Date = GetDate();
 Select * from Items where Convert(date, DueDate) = @today
```

This seems to work until late in the evening, at which point it returns rows which are actually due the next day.

The issue: GetDate(), because it is a Sql Server running on Azure, actually returns GetUTCDate().  So at 9PM EST, the date it returns is not today, but tomorrow, because the UTC time is 5 hours ahead (2AM, the following day).

I had made `@today` a date so that the time portion could be ignored.

But in the database, DueDate is `2018-12-02 05:00:00.0000000 +00:00`  But when this is cast to a date, the date is `2018-12-02`, but `@today` is `2018-12-03`

So how should I write this SQL?

Comment: I would pass the date into the query rather than using `getdate()` because even though you can adjust the date to suit, then you have to take into account daylight saving, and if you should move your database to a different server your dates will change.

Comment: There's a few ways to alter timezones. `SWITCHOFFSET()` has worked since 2008 and newer versions of SQL Server (2016+) have `AT TIME ZONE`.

Comment: what is the data type of [DueDate]? see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Used_By_Already,  DueDate is a DateTimeOffset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place "today" into a time zone, consider the 2 queries below (notice how "today" is set) see [AT TIME ZONE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> ```
> declare @today as datetimeoffset;
> SET @today = cast(getdate() as date);
>
> ;with Items as (
>     select -24 as n, dateadd(hour,-24,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) as DueDate
>     
>     union all
>     
>     select n+1, dateadd(hour,n+1,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
>     from Items
>     where n < 24
>     )
>
> Select * , @today
> from Items 
> where DueDate >= @today and DueDate < dateadd(day,1,@today)
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>   n | DueDate                    | (No column name)          
> --: | :------------------------- | :-------------------------
> -10 | 03/12/2018 00:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  -9 | 03/12/2018 01:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  -8 | 03/12/2018 02:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  -7 | 03/12/2018 03:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  -6 | 03/12/2018 04:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  -5 | 03/12/2018 05:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  -4 | 03/12/2018 06:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  -3 | 03/12/2018 07:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  -2 | 03/12/2018 08:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  -1 | 03/12/2018 09:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>   0 | 03/12/2018 10:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>   1 | 03/12/2018 11:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>   2 | 03/12/2018 12:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>   3 | 03/12/2018 13:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>   4 | 03/12/2018 14:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>   5 | 03/12/2018 15:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>   6 | 03/12/2018 16:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>   7 | 03/12/2018 17:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>   8 | 03/12/2018 18:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>   9 | 03/12/2018 19:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  10 | 03/12/2018 20:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  11 | 03/12/2018 21:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  12 | 03/12/2018 22:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
>  13 | 03/12/2018 23:57:54 +00:00 | 03/12/2018 00:00:00 +00:00
> ```

> ```
> declare @today as datetimeoffset;
> SET @today = cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetimeoffset) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time';
>
> ;with Items as (
>     select -24 as n, dateadd(hour,-24,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()) as DueDate
>     
>     union all
>     
>     select n+1, dateadd(hour,n+1,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())
>     from Items
>     where n < 24
>     )
>
> Select * , @today
> from Items 
> where DueDate >= @today and DueDate < dateadd(day,1,@today)
> ;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>   n | DueDate                    | (No column name)          
> --: | :------------------------- | :-------------------------
> -10 | 03/12/2018 00:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  -9 | 03/12/2018 01:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  -8 | 03/12/2018 02:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  -7 | 03/12/2018 03:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  -6 | 03/12/2018 04:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  -5 | 03/12/2018 05:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  -4 | 03/12/2018 06:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  -3 | 03/12/2018 07:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  -2 | 03/12/2018 08:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  -1 | 03/12/2018 09:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>   0 | 03/12/2018 10:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>   1 | 03/12/2018 11:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>   2 | 03/12/2018 12:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>   3 | 03/12/2018 13:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>   4 | 03/12/2018 14:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>   5 | 03/12/2018 15:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>   6 | 03/12/2018 16:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>   7 | 03/12/2018 17:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>   8 | 03/12/2018 18:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>   9 | 03/12/2018 19:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  10 | 03/12/2018 20:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  11 | 03/12/2018 21:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  12 | 03/12/2018 22:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
>  13 | 03/12/2018 23:57:54 +00:00 | 02/12/2018 16:00:00 -08:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aabd584026a185006be540659079c0ae)*

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it was very helpful.

Comment: pleasure, please also note how I dealt with the predicate to filter, this is particularly important here I believe, but you should try to avoid changing the column to be "today" , use a range instead.